# Put a doClick inside a JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am a beginner to java and I have some trouble on making the doClick buttons. I don't understand how it works and I need it in my code.

```
     JButton easyb  = new JButton("Easy");
     JButton mediumb = new JButton("Medium");
     JButton hardb = new JButton("Hard");

    String fn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose your level \n", easyb.doClick() ,mediumb.doClick(), hardb.doClick() , "\n \n Easy are words you know everyday \n Medium are words that you have seen before \n Hard are words that you have rarely seen in your life");
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
    Choose your level
    easy   medium   hard ( you can click on the words)

    Easy are words you have said everyday
    Medium are words that you have seen before
    Hard are words that you have rarely seen in your life
```

**Update**:
 Here is my whole code in case you need anything else

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class SWG1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int pizza = 0;
    while(pizza == 0){  
        String[] options = { "Easy", "Medium", "Hard" };

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Scrable", "Game", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        String fn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose your level \n", easyb.doClick() ,mediumb.doClick(), hardb.doClick() , "\n \n Easy are words you know everyday \n Medium are words that you have seen before \n Hard are words that you have rarley seen in your life"); 


        String[] easy = {"the","car","jump","that","have","with","on","to","you","this","from","game","video","ball","about","which","know","people","year","get","also"};
        String[] medium = {"abolish","abuse","absurb","access","accomplish","achievement","aggressive","bland","bungle","challenge","combine","crave","frigid","gorge","hazy","oasis","perish","retire","seldom","tropical","vivid","withdraw"};
        String[] hard = {"allusion","bard","characterization","indirect","direct","colloquial","dialect","elegy","farce","genre","humor","jargon","tone","vernacular","unbashed"};

        int x = 0;
        int chelp = 0; 

        while(x == 0){
            if(fn.equals("Easy") || fn.equals("easy")){
                int index = new Random().nextInt(easy.length);

                String randomWord = easy[index];
                //System.out.println("Random word: '" + randomWord + "'. It is of length: " + randomWord.length());
                int c = 0;

                while(c == 0){
                    Random r = new Random();
                    randomWord = scramble( r, randomWord );
                    if(randomWord.equals(easy[index])){
                        c = 0;
                    }
                    else{
                        c = 1;
                    }
                }


                int b = 0;
                while(b == 0){
                    String gn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(randomWord);

                    if(gn.equals(easy[index])){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct", "Good Job", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                        b = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chelp++;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, you are wrong", "Bad Job", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                        String hn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to quit \n Yes \n No");
                        if(hn.equals("Yes") || hn.equals("yes")){
                            b = 1;
                        }
                        if(chelp == 3){

                        }
                    }
            }
            }

            if(fn.equals("Medium") || fn.equals("medium")){
                int index1 = new Random().nextInt(medium.length);

                String randomWord1 = medium[index1];
                ///System.out.println("Random word: '" + randomWord1 + "'. It is of length: " + randomWord1.length());

                int q = 0;

                while(q == 0){
                    Random r1 = new Random();
                    randomWord1 = scramble( r1, randomWord1 );
                    if(randomWord1.equals(easy[index1])){
                        q = 0;
                    }
                    else{
                        q = 1;
                    }
                }

                int z = 0;
                while(z == 0){
                    String gn1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(randomWord1);

                    if(gn1.equals(easy[index1])){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct", "Good Job", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                        z = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, you are wrong", "Bad Job", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                        String hn1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to quit \n Yes \n No");
                        if(hn1.equals("Yes") || hn1.equals("yes")){
                            z = 1;
                        }
                    }
            }
            }

            if(fn.equals("Hard") || fn.equals("hard")){
                int index2 = new Random().nextInt(hard.length);

                String randomWord2 = hard[index2];
                //System.out.println("Random word: '" + randomWord2 + "'. It is of length: " + randomWord2.length());

                int h = 0;

                while(h == 0){
                    Random r2 = new Random();
                    randomWord2 = scramble( r2, randomWord2 );
                    if(randomWord2.equals(easy[index2])){
                        h = 0;
                    }
                    else{
                        h = 1;
                    }
                }

                int y = 0;

                while(y == 0){
                    String gn2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(randomWord2);

                    if(gn2.equals(easy[index2])){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct", "Good Job", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                        y = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, you are wrong", "Bad Job", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                        String hn2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to quit \n Yes \n No");
                        if(hn2.equals("Yes") || hn2.equals("yes")){
                            y = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            String quitn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to continue \n Yes \n No");

            if(quitn.equals("No") || quitn.equals("no")){
                x = 1;
            }

            }
        String quitn1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to quit the game \n Yes \n No");

        if(quitn1.equals("Yes") || quitn1.equals("yes")){
            System.exit(1);
        }
        }
        }


    public static String scramble( Random random, String inputString )
    {
        char a[] = inputString.toCharArray();

        for( int i=0 ; i<a.length-1 ; i++ )
        {
            int j = random.nextInt(a.length-1);
            // Swap letters
            char temp = a[i]; a[i] = a[j];  a[j] = temp;
        }       

        return new String( a );
    }}
```

If you have any questions comment below.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a better JOptionPane, the `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog`:

```
  String[] options = { "Easy", "Medium", "Hard" };
  int selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choose Something", "Title",
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
        options, options[0]);


  // ***** oops! this should be >= 0, not > 0. Corrected!
  if (selection >= 0) {
     System.out.println("Selected: " + options[selection]);
  }
```

---

**Edit**
From your comments:

> The button part works but I have two problems. The first is that I don't think it will show how I want the output to be like I said in my question. The words need to be there as well.

All you need to do is put in if/else blocks or perhaps better, a switch statement that outputs the correct String based on which option was selected, 0, 1, or 2.

e.g.,

```
if (selection >= 0) {
   String word = options[selection];
   case selection 0: 
      // output stuff based on easy
      break;
   case selection 1:
      // output stuff based on medium selection,....
      break;
   //.... etc.../
}
```

> The second problem will show the whole code and then you can see the problem.

I see your whole code, but I don't see a specific question pertaining to it.

---

**Edit 2**
What Ordous is suggesting is that you create a JPanel with your 3 buttons, give them ActionListeners, and place that JPanel into a JOptionPane or into a JDialog, and display it.

Comment: The button part works but I have two problems. The first is that I don't think it will show how I want the output to be like I said in my question. The words need to be there as well. The second problem will show the whole code and then you can see the problem.

Comment: @user3829667 You know you can just pass a custom component instead of a String to the JOptionPane and customize it however you like, right?

Comment: @Ordous I am sorry but I have no idea what you are saying

Comment: @Ordus Can you put your answer down below in the answer box. That would help me so much

Comment: @user3829667: also there was an error in my example code where I had `if (selection  > 0)`. It should be `if (selection >= 0)`