# doClick inside JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am a beginner to java, and I need some help. This is my code.

```
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class SWG1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      int pizza = 0;
      while(pizza == 0){    
      String[] options = { "Easy", "Medium", "Hard" };

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Scrable", "Game", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
      String fn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose your level \n", easyb.doClick() ,mediumb.doClick(), hardb.doClick() , "\n \n Easy are words you know everyday \n Medium are words that you have seen before \n Hard are words that you have rarley seen in your life"); 


      String[] easy = {"the","car","jump","that","have","with","on","to","you","this","from","game","video","ball","about","which","know","people","year","get","also"};
      String[] medium = {"abolish","abuse","absurb","access","accomplish","achievement","aggressive","bland","bungle","challenge","combine","crave","frigid","gorge","hazy","oasis","perish","retire","seldom","tropical","vivid","withdraw"};
      String[] hard = {"allusion","bard","characterization","indirect","direct","colloquial","dialect","elegy","farce","genre","humor","jargon","tone","vernacular","unbashed"};

      int x = 0;

      while(x == 0){
         if(fn.equals("Easy") || fn.equals("easy")){
             int index = new Random().nextInt(easy.length);

             String randomWord = easy[index];
             //System.out.println("Random word: '" + randomWord + "'. It is of length: " + randomWord.length());
             int c = 0;

             while(c == 0){
                Random r = new Random();
                randomWord = scramble( r, randomWord );
                if(randomWord.equals(easy[index])){
                    c = 0;
                }
                else{
                    c = 1;
                }
            }


            int b = 0;
            while(b == 0){
                String gn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(randomWord);

                if(gn.equals(easy[index])){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct", "Good Job", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    b = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, you are wrong", "Bad Job", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    String hn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to quit \n Yes \n No");
                    if(hn.equals("Yes") || hn.equals("yes")){
                        b = 1;
                    }
                }
        }
        }

        if(fn.equals("Medium") || fn.equals("medium")){
            int index1 = new Random().nextInt(medium.length);

            String randomWord1 = medium[index1];
            ///System.out.println("Random word: '" + randomWord1 + "'. It is of length: " + randomWord1.length());

            int q = 0;

            while(q == 0){
                Random r1 = new Random();
                randomWord1 = scramble( r1, randomWord1 );
                if(randomWord1.equals(easy[index1])){
                    q = 0;
                }
                else{
                    q = 1;
                }
            }

            int z = 0;
            while(z == 0){
                String gn1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(randomWord1);

                if(gn1.equals(easy[index1])){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct", "Good Job", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    z = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, you are wrong", "Bad Job", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    String hn1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to quit \n Yes \n No");
                    if(hn1.equals("Yes") || hn1.equals("yes")){
                        z = 1;
                    }
                }
        }
        }

        if(fn.equals("Hard") || fn.equals("hard")){
            int index2 = new Random().nextInt(hard.length);

            String randomWord2 = hard[index2];
            //System.out.println("Random word: '" + randomWord2 + "'. It is of length: " + randomWord2.length());

            int h = 0;

            while(h == 0){
                Random r2 = new Random();
                randomWord2 = scramble( r2, randomWord2 );
                if(randomWord2.equals(easy[index2])){
                    h = 0;
                }
                else{
                    h = 1;
                }
            }

            int y = 0;

            while(y == 0){
                String gn2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(randomWord2);

                if(gn2.equals(easy[index2])){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct", "Good Job", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    y = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, you are wrong", "Bad Job", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    String hn2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to quit \n Yes \n No");
                    if(hn2.equals("Yes") || hn2.equals("yes")){
                        y = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        String quitn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to continue \n Yes \n No");

        if(quitn.equals("No") || quitn.equals("no")){
            x = 1;
        }

        }
        String quitn1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to quit the game \n Yes \n No");

        if(quitn1.equals("Yes") || quitn1.equals("yes")){
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    }


    public static String scramble( Random random, String inputString )
    {
       char a[] = inputString.toCharArray();

       for( int i=0 ; i<a.length-1 ; i++ )
       {
           int j = random.nextInt(a.length-1);
           // Swap letters
           char temp = a[i]; a[i] = a[j];  a[j] = temp;
       }       

       return new String( a );
   }
}
```

I need help with this line

`String fn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose your level \n", easyb.doClick()          ,mediumb.doClick(), hardb.doClick() , "\n \n Easy are words you know everyday 
\n Medium are words that you have seen before \n Hard are words that you have rarley seen in your life");`

I want the output to look like exactly this

```
   Choose your level 

   Easy Medium Hard (You can click on these words)

    Easy are words you know everyday
    Medium are words that you have seen before
    Hard are words that you have rarley seen in your life
```

I also want these if statments to be changed so that it is equal to whatever I click

`if(fn.equals("Easy") || fn.equals("easy"))`

`if(fn.equals("Medium") || fn.equals("medium"))`

`if(fn.equals("Hard") || fn.equals("hard"))`

Please write you answer in code and not in writing. Thank you.

Comment: _"Please write you answer in code and not in writing"._ - Fail! Please don't make those kind of _gimme da codez_ requests. You're basically saying, "Please do my homework for me. You don't have to explain your answer, I just need the code to turn in".

Comment: If you just want code without explanations, then good look learning

Comment: @peeskillet: This is nothing but a duplicate question that I had already answered in his [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699590/put-a-doclick-inside-a-joptionpane).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
String[] difficultyOptions = new String[] {"Easy", "Medium", "Hard"};
int response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Message:  Choose Your Difficulty:", "Title:  Difficulty Selection",
    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
    null, options, options[0]);

switch(response) {
    case 0:
        //this is for easy
        break;
    case 1:
        //this is for medium
        break;
    case 2:
        //this is for hard
        break;
}
```

Comment: so just to be clear, inside the case is where i put the other information

Comment: Correct. Like if you wanted the console to read something about easy you would add this to case 0. System.out.println("you clicked on easy.");

Comment: Okay. Ask anything you'd like

Comment: first thing is that the break means that its going to break out of the case, right

Comment: Yes the break is to tell it to break case when condition is met. You should also use a default case as well though some do and some do not see it as a necessity.

Comment: Okay second thing is that there are other parts were you mainly say yes or no and it's the same deal as this question. Should I do the same thing for that or is there an easier way

Comment: You could do it this way though there is just a yes no option. I'll place a code example in another answer block as I can not do code from my phone in a comment block.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pane with yes and no options

```
int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, title, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
      //if yes is clicked do this stuff
} else if(JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
      //do no stuff
}
```